# weird "unable to match function definition"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I have

```
class ObjectController
{
public:
...
    template<template<class> class Action, class T>
    Action<T> * createAction(typename Action<T>::CommandFunction cf, T * t)
    {
        return new Action<T>(cf, t);
    }
...
};
```

and everything works just fine...
But I am used to have only declarations in my classes and definitions in other file... (*.inl for templates)... But when I move this code outside the class ObjectController like this:

```
class ObjectController
{
public:
...
    template<template<class> class Action, class T>
    Action<T> * createAction(typename Action<T>::CommandFunction cf, T * t);
...
};

template<template<class> class Action, class T>
Action<T> * ObjectController::createAction(typename Action<T>::CommandFunction cf, T * t)
{
    return new Action<T>(cf, t);
}
```

I get:

```
unable to match function definition to an existing declaration definition
'Action<T> *gear::core::ObjectController::createAction(Action<T>::CommandFunction,T *)'
existing declarations
'Action<T> *gear::core::ObjectController::createAction(Action<T>::CommandFunction,T *)'
```

How can I solve it?

**edit**
when I take exact code from KennyTM (see comments) and paste it to my VS2010 I get the same error... Can somebody confirm it?

Comment: no-repro. http://ideone.com/12TFH

Comment: @KennyTM when I take exactly the code from ideone and paste it to the empty new project I get the same error

Comment: I get same compilation failure in VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug.
I have submitted it to Microsoft

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/724362/unable-to-match-function-definition

The fix should show up in the next release of Visual C++.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Visual Studio 2005 that prevents certain "outlined" template functions from compiling correctly.

There is a hotfix available here.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930198